# Unexpected Outputs in a simple FizzBuzz program in C++

Tags: c++, output, stdmap, stdstring

I was just trying my hand at implementing a simple FizzBuzz program where I'm trying to separate the ruleset from the logic and here is my attempt at doing this within Compiler Explorer, no use of any IDE or debugging tools.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<uint32_t,std::string> RuleSet;

RuleSet ruleSet { {3, "fizz"},
                  {5, "buzz"}
};

void fizzBuzz(int32_t max_limit, RuleSet rules) {
    std::string output{""};
    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < max_limit; i++) {        

        for (auto r : rules) {
            if ( (i % r.first) == 0 ) {
                output = r.second;
            } else {
                output = std::to_string(i);
            }
        }
        output.append(1, '\n');
        std::cout << output;
        output.clear();
    }
}

int main() {
    fizzBuzz(100, ruleSet);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a link to it in compiler explorer: [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4nfMejoao)

Within the execution unit, It's printing the number values, and it's printing buzz, but for the life of me, I'm trying to figure out why it's not printing fizz anywhere... Any kind of hint or suggestion or insight as to why I'm getting the output that am I would be helpful. Please take note that I'm not writing this or running it in an IDE as I currently do not have access to a debugger to step through my code. This was implemented directly in Compiler Explorer. I know I'm overlooking something but any help at this point is appreciated.

---

The expected output should be:

```
1
2
fizz
4
buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizzbuzz
// and so on...
```

Here's the actual output that I'm getting from Compiler Explorer:

```
1
2
3
4
buzz
6
7
8
9
buzz
11
12
13
14
buzz
16
17
18
19
buzz
21
22
23
24
buzz
26
27
28
29
buzz
31
32
33
34
buzz
36
37
38
39
buzz
41
42
43
44
buzz
46
47
48
49
buzz
51
52
53
54
buzz
56
57
58
59
buzz
61
62
63
64
buzz
66
67
68
69
buzz
71
72
73
74
buzz
76
77
78
79
buzz
81
82
83
84
buzz
86
87
88
89
buzz
91
92
93
94
buzz
96
97
98
99
```

Comment: A single if-else is not enough. You have to test **all** the rules first, to see that none of them match.

Comment: Mention your current output and expected output. Also see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: If you don't have access to an actual debugger, which is really a must to be able to program, use other [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) techniques. Like writing lots of output, or explaining in great detail to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I did provide a link to Compiler explorer with the given outputs... The expected outputs should be self explanatory for the nature of a FizzBuzz function/program...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Providing a link is not enough. Everything needed for clarity should be included in the question as text. Links gets broken/change often.

Comment: I can update the question then...

Comment: The rules loop will overwrite the output on every pass, so in effect, only the last rule will be used. Adding s print in the loop or using a debugger would help you see that problem yourself.

Comment: *"here is my attempt at doing this within Compiler Explorer, no use of any IDE or debugging tools."* We can't debug your program for you. You must first do(at least try) it yourself. Here is a [online debugging](https://onlinegdb.com/nx8Ute9B5) site/page.

Comment: I typically use either Visual Studio or VSCode but I don't have access to them and would normally debug it myself. I just didn't have access to an actual debugger, and I wasn't aware of any "online debugging" tools, I'll have to check out the site link provided by user @user12002570.

Comment: @FrancisCugler The problem is that you don't have a `break` statement inside the `if` block when the condition `i%r.first` is met. To solve this add a `break` statement and you'll get your expected output as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547421/12002570).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're overwriting the results every time you go through the inner loop, so only the last rule has any effect. What you probably want to do is use append, and then convert from the number if the results are still empty. Something like the following:

```
for ( int i = 1; i < max_limit; ++ i ) {
    std::string         output;
    for ( auto r: rules ) {
        if ( i % r.first == 0 ) {
            output += r.second;
        }
    }
    if ( ! output.empty() ) {
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I might add that you probably want to pass `Rules` by `const` reference, rather than by value.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you're not breaking out of the inner for loop when the condition `(i % r.first)` is met. This can be easily seen either using a debugger or adding `std::cout`.

Basically you *need to break out of the inner for loop as soon as the condition is satisfied(after setting the `output` in your example)*.

Thus to get your expected output, just add a `break` statement inside the `if` block as shown [below](https://godbolt.org/z/3jEnrvqoo):

```
for (auto r : rules) {
    if ( (i % r.first) == 0 ) {
        output = r.second;
//------vvvvv------------------>added this break statement 
        break;
    } else {
        output = std::to_string(i);
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3jEnrvqoo)

After making this change, the output is as in your expected output:

```
1
2
fizz
4
buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizz
16
17
fizz
19
buzz
fizz
22
23
fizz
buzz
26
fizz
28
29
fizz
31
32
fizz
34
buzz
fizz
37
38
fizz
buzz
41
fizz
43
44
fizz
46
47
fizz
49
buzz
fizz
52
53
fizz
buzz
56
fizz
58
59
fizz
61
62
fizz
64
buzz
fizz
67
68
fizz
buzz
71
fizz
73
74
fizz
76
77
fizz
79
buzz
fizz
82
83
fizz
buzz
86
fizz
88
89
fizz
91
92
fizz
94
buzz
fizz
97
98
fizz
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking. It was leaving the loop after the initial condition was met that I was missing. Your answer-resolution to this problem is appreciated. I've been out of practice from the language for a little over a year and I knew I was overlooking something simple... I just wasn't able to see it, needed a 2nd set of eyes to point me in the right direction. Thank You!

Comment: Well, it's still not generating the output exactly as intended for when the occurrence of a rule set such as being divisible by say both `3` and `5` are met then both `fizz` and `buzz` should be printed on the same line, however, I can consider that a different problem. And for that I may have to change the output from `std::string` to a `std::stringstream` object instead..

Comment: In other words, if you look at my list of expected outputs when we reach the value where 15 would be, the displayed text should be `fizzbuzz` not `fizz`, and this should occur every time a value is divisible by each rule within the rule set, so due to this, I kept the upvote for your answer because it did help, yet I had to remove the check mark as solution to the problem. Your generated output does not match my expected output.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Yes, the may be more logical problems(like maybe you want to append to `output` like `output+= r.second` instead of assigning to it) but they can too be solved by simply using a debugger or adding your own `std::cout` at different places.

Comment: True, and I'm use to working in Visual Studio in a full IDE with a debugger and everything else... I'm just trying to work out a few common problems here and there so that I don't fully lose the fundamentals of my programming skills. I'm not trying to be overly pedantic about it, this isn't being used in any kind of production code, etc... It's just a quick brush up from an algorithmic perspective.